# Installing dependencies from downloaded folder with Windows CMD

Tags: python, windows, macos, pip

I'll try to make this as concise as possible.

I have got a Python project on a Mac that I want to distribute to multiple Windows computers. Before I distribute the zipped (that's what I do now at least) files, I'm downloading all dependencies to a folder named "dependencies" with the following command:
`pip download -r requirements.txt -d "./dependencies"`

I then zip the contents of the entire project folder using:
`zip -r everything.zip .`

I then (manually, for now) transfer the file to the Windows computer, where i unzip the contents of the zip-file using:
`“%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\winrar.exe” x -ibck C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\test_env\everything.zip *.* C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\test_env\`

So far, so good. However, when I navigate into the dependencies-folder and try to install the dependencies offline using:
`pip install * -f ./ --no-index`

I get the following error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '*'

The same command works perfectly fine on my Mac, but I can't seem to find the equivalent for Windows CMD.

Any input?

PS! If anyone has any tips on how to best distribute the zip file, unzip it and install the dependencies to x number of computers, it would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried multiple commands, but end up getting different errors.

```
zip -r everything.zip .
“%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\winrar.exe” x -ibck C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\test_env\everything.zip *.* C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\test_env\
pip install * -f ./ --no-index
```

I expected pip install * -f ./ --no-index to work, but it gave me the following error message: ERROR: Invalid requirement: '*'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:-

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///path/to/packages/folder
```

If you want to do it through a code.

```
import pip

def install(package_name): 
   pip.main(["install", "--upgrade", "--no-index", "--find-links=.", package_name]) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
list_of_dependencies= [" Dep1","dep2"]
for dependency in list_of_dependencies:
     install(dependency)
```